# Which algorithm is used for Checksum(), Binary_Checksum() and CHECKSUM_AVG() function in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, hash, checksum

`Checksum()`, `Binary_Checksum()` and `CHECKSUM_AVG()` functions are provided by SQL Server to build a hash index based on an expression or a column list.
This can be helpful in determining whether a row has changed or not. The mechanism can then be used to identify whether the record has been updated or not.

I have found lots of example of collisions that are generated same hash value for different values. How we can identify the collision condition for these function.

Anyone have to clue about to which algorithm or technique used to generated/compute hash without hash collisions?

Comment: Your Question a not correct format. describe more and check StackOverflow guideline please share some code sample. what problem you face.

Comment: I have tried Checksum() and Binary_checksum() function to generate hash value but for some values its generates duplicate hash value. so hash values are collide. Do you any clue to generate  hash without collision of hash value.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [CHECKSUM weakness explained](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/peterl/archive/2010/08/19/checksum-weakness-explained.aspx) article on sqlTeam:

> The built-in CHECKUM function in SQL Server is built on a series of 4 bit left rotational xor operations.

A [forum post from 2006](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=70832) (linked in the article as well) posted by Peter Larsson inlcudes sql user defined functions that computes checksum. Author of the post claims to 100% compatibility with SQL Server's built in function (I haven't tested it myself).

In case the link goes dead, here is a copy of the relevant part:

> With text/varchar/image data, call with SELECT `BINARY_CHECKSUM('abcdefghijklmnop')`, `dbo.fnPesoBinaryChecksum('abcdefghijklmnop')`
> With integer data, call with `SELECT BINARY_CHECKSUM(123)`, `dbo.fnPesoBinaryChecksum(CAST(123 AS VARBINARY))`
> I haven't figured out how to calculate checksum for integers greater than 255 yet.
>
> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnPesoBinaryChecksum
> (
>     @Data IMAGE
> )
> RETURNS INT
> AS
>
> BEGIN
>     DECLARE @Index INT,
>         @MaxIndex INT,
>         @SUM BIGINT,
>         @Overflow TINYINT
>
>     SELECT  @Index = 1,
>         @MaxIndex = DATALENGTH(@Data),
>         @SUM = 0
>
>     WHILE @Index <= @MaxIndex
>         SELECT  @SUM = (16 * @SUM) ^ SUBSTRING(@Data, @Index, 1),
>             @Overflow = @SUM / 4294967296,
>             @SUM = @SUM - @Overflow * 4294967296,
>             @SUM = @SUM ^ @Overflow,
>             @Index = @Index + 1
>
>     IF @SUM > 2147483647
>         SET @SUM = @SUM - 4294967296
>     ELSE IF @SUM BETWEEN 32768 AND 65535
>         SET @SUM = @SUM - 65536
>     ELSE IF @SUM BETWEEN 128 AND 255
>         SET @SUM = @SUM - 256
>
>     RETURN @SUM
> END
> ```
>
> > Actually this is an improvement of MS function, since it accepts TEXT and IMAGE data.
>
> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnPesoTextChecksum]
> (
>     @Data TEXT
> )
> RETURNS INT
> AS
>
> BEGIN
>     DECLARE @Index INT,
>         @MaxIndex INT,
>         @SUM BIGINT,
>         @Overflow TINYINT
>
>     SELECT  @Index = 1,
>         @MaxIndex = DATALENGTH(@Data),
>         @SUM = 0
>
>     WHILE @Index <= @MaxIndex
>         SELECT  @SUM = (16 * @SUM) ^ ASCII(SUBSTRING(@Data, @Index, 1)),
>             @Overflow = @SUM / 4294967296,
>             @SUM = @SUM - @Overflow * 4294967296,
>             @SUM = @SUM ^ @Overflow,
>             @Index = @Index + 1
>
>     IF @SUM > 2147483647
>         SET @SUM = @SUM - 4294967296
>     ELSE IF @SUM BETWEEN 32768 AND 65535
>         SET @SUM = @SUM - 65536
>     ELSE IF @SUM BETWEEN 128 AND 255
>         SET @SUM = @SUM - 256
>
>     RETURN  @SUM
> END
> ```

Another good read is [Exploring Hash Functions In SQL Server](https://web.archive.org/web/20220705010823/http://blog.kejser.org/exploring-hash-functions-in-sql-server/) by Thomas Kejser, where the author checks the built in hash functions in sql server for speed an quality.

Answer (score 1):

PHP implementation of BINARY_CHECKSUM:

```php
$input = 'binary string';
$sum = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($input); $i++) {
    $sum = ($sum << 4) ^ ord($in[$i]);
    $sum = ($sum & 0xffffffff) ^ ($sum >> 32);
}
return $sum > 0x7fffffff ? $sum - 0x100000000 : $sum;
```